# Firebase realtime database rule - auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

if my data structure is like the following (example: an array of books)

```
     books: 
           0 :    name = book1,
                    id= 123

           1: name = book2,
                id = 456

           2: name = book3,
                id = 789
```

how can I grant read and write access in firebase realtime database for the '/books' url? Please note that my 'auth.id' matches the 'id' inside each book.

so the data is (books/0/id == auth.id) but the url access to read and write is for '/books'. Is there a way to use the id and grant access at a parent level?

I tried the following,

```
        "rules"
             "books" 
                  "$id" {".read" : $id == auth.uid}
```

but no luck..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with arrays, I guess that `$id` captures just the index. So, you'd try the following:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "books": {
      "$book_index": {
        ".read" : "data.child('id').val() == auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions

Comment: Hey this didn't work either. But what worked temporarily was the following `{
  "rules": {
    "books": {
        ".read" :  "root.child('books').child('0').child('id').val() == auth.uid"
      
    }
  }
}` However, here I need to find a way to replace the ".child(0)" which is the book index 0, as a dynamic variable. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: What about `root.child('books').child($book_index).child('id').val()`?

Comment: In that case I will have to create `{   "rules": {     "books": {    "$books": {    ".read" :  "root.child('books').child($book_index).child('id').val() == auth.uid"            }   } }` which means this will work for the path as **'/books/0'** rather than **'/books'**. I want to grant access to read and write for **"/books"**.  which is why I am wondering if there is a way to access a child variable but grant access only for its parent path

Comment: I don't think it's possible: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#read_and_write_rules_cascade